# MySql: Authentication method 'caching_sha2_password' failed

Tags: mysql, .net

Trying to connect to MySql from .net started giving me the following error:

```
Authentication method 'caching_sha2_password' failed. Either use a secure connection, specify the server's RSA public key with ServerRSAPublicKeyFile, or set AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some weird reason, the solution is to sign into the server using MySql Workbench, and then the server will start accepting connections again.

Comment: Any idea why it does this? It started happening to me recently and it's been very odd. For me if I connect from a different client (like my Debian WSL command line) then it works for me. My dotnet project is running on my Windows machine (not WSL).